# Illustrator: Renaming <Group> and <Compound Path> layers or not?

Tags: layers, caveats, best-practice

It may very well be a subjective question, but, is it a good habit not to rename `<Group>` and `<Compound Path>` layers? My main hesitation of doing so is that I loose track of what it is.

Once renamed, is there a way to easily differentiate grouped objects (e.g., initially-named `<Group>` or `<Compund path>`) from 'normal' layers and paths? Any rationale appreciated.

Comment: I rename everything if needed. You can use <Foo> and include the brackets to indicate a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a **BAD** habit to not rename your layers.  Regardless of whether they're simple or complex, grouped or solitary, et cetera, et cetera, et cetera - you should *always* name your layers!

When you need to get something done quickly, there are few things more annoying than opening a PSD or AI file with dozens of unnamed layers and objects.  When this happens, there is no easy way to get right to the work you need to do - whether it be slicing for production, or just making modifications.  You instead have to familiarize yourself with the programmatic structure of the document instead of simply working with the artistic elements of the document.

Even if you don't work with any other artists or developers, do it for yourself.  If you ever have to revisit that file (and it will undoubtedly happen long after you've forgotten the intimate details of the composition), you will be happy you did.

**Update:**

I see what you're saying now, and I second Alan's recommendation about prefixing/tokenizing the objects.  Perhaps rename something to "Group: {Description}" or something similar.

I frequently have constructs like this:
[image: Group naming convention example]

Comment: Right. But my concern was about the latter: E.g. after grouping a bunch of layers, then changing the non-descriptive name `<Group>` to something more useful; how do you keep track of whether it's a *group* or not (as opposed to a normal layer with a bunch of paths inside, which is pretty different). I definitely agree with your notion of naming layers, this should be anyone's frequent habit and so forth – but, sometimes I'm thinking if it might be wiser putting e.g. a <Group>'s inside a new Layer, renaming *that* layer instead of the <Group>, so as to easily stay aware of its <Group> status.

Comment: Does that make sense? :) For example, you have one layer that's named A and one group that's named <Group>. You rename <Group> to B. Now, how do you know by looking in the Layers Palette that B is a Group and A is not?

Comment: Just rename <Group> to "Group A" or "grp_A" to keep track. @Farray: Want to add that to your answer?

Comment: Alan: yes, tokenizing a group might be a workable option. Perhaps the best there is. (I have yet to try that.) Although having to do so feels kind of half baked compared to just knowing/seeing that a particular layer is either a group/compound path/layer/path, directly, in the Layers palette …Is there any way this can be accomplished? If not, I wonder if anyone else has stopped for a while, reflecting upon this? Maybe it's just me? :-)

Comment: @hced - thanks for the clarification, I did not fully understand what you were asking the first time.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson Added!  Grazie...

Comment: @Farray Prego! :-)

Comment: Thanks, Farray and Alan. It's odd why there is no indicator in AI's Layer list, that shows if layers are <Group>, <Compound path>, etc.

Comment: @hced Theoretically you can assign colors to different layers and this would differentiate objects that belong to various layers/sublayers/etc.  However, AI (at least CS3) is very buggy when applying the colors.  It's not quite that there's no indicator in the Layer view, it's just very poorly implemented.

Comment: Problem is that one can't color what is technically a <Group>, <Compund path> or <Path> – only 'Layers' can be colored. However, this discrepancy might actually be somewhat handy, in the sense that you  can then double-click things in the Layer palette and if you can't color it, you know it's at least not a Layer. ;)